# programatically check new versions for eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to Eclipse plugin development. I am developing a plugin which is only available inside an intranet and the user has to be prompted everytime a new version of the plugin is available. The plugin has an update site.

Whats the best way to do this? Is it possible to install the new version programatically?

I am targeting Eclipse 3.4 and higher.

Comment: Since you are on an Intranet, I'm assuming you work for a company that has a policy wrt the IDE setup. It would help if you restrict your question to a specific version of Eclipse. The whole software installation scheme has changed a lot between the versions over the years.

Comment: I am targeting Eclipse 3.4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Under preferences: `Install/Update -> Automatic Updates` you can check `Automatically find new update and notify me`.

[image]

Comment: This setting will check updates for all plugins. I want only the plugin that i develop to be checked on startup. In fact, the IT department for my company doesn't allow automatic updates.